# Image Pattern/texture Matching in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-matching

I am trying to match two images having the same pattern/texture but different intensities as shown below.
 [image]

I have tried calculating the difference in gradient magnitude and direction of the two images and threshold it. The output was poor as shown below. The two images have the same texture and i want to detect them as same. Is there a better way to do this? I am expecting the output to be almost all black.

[image]

The code:

```
[Gx,Gy] = imgradientxy(rgb2gray(I3),'sobel');
[mag, dir] = imgradient(Gx, Gy);
[Gx1,Gy1] = imgradientxy(rgb2gray(I2),'sobel');
[mag1, dir1] = imgradient(Gx1, Gy1);
imshow(abs(mag-mag1)>35,[]);
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the different color planes, like HSV or YCbCr. Since your images show a intensity variation, use HSV. I took your two images and resultant turns out as below when y-plane in YCbCr color space is considered.

```
I = imread('1.jpg');
I2 = imread('2.jpg');
[r,c] = size(I2(:,:,3));
I=imresize(I, [r, c]);
imshow(I);
I = rgb2ycbcr(I);
I2 = rgb2ycbcr(I2);
[Gx,Gy] = imgradientxy(I(:,:,1),'sobel'); %y-plane
[mag, dir] = imgradient(Gx, Gy);
[Gx1,Gy1] = imgradientxy(I2(:,:,1),'sobel'); %y-plane
[mag1, dir1] = imgradient(Gx1, Gy1);
imshow(imerode(abs(mag-mag1)>120,1),[])
```

you can try out different planes from different color spaces until you get your desired intensity-invariant pattern in image.

Comment: My output image cannot be posted because I'm new to stackoverflow and it needs minimum 10 reps to include any image!

Comment: The y channel is basically the intensity channel and is similar to gray-scale. Same in case of HSV. Thanks.